# Visual Studio 2012 Object Data Source

Tags: visual-studio-2012, datasource, objectdatasource

In Visual Studio versions prior to 2012 you could open the Data Source tool window, click the add data source button select object and navigate the project namespace hierarchy to a class (business object). Visual Studio 2012, out of the box, doesn't allow you to simply select a class anymore. My question is how do I add a data source based on a business object to my project in Visual Studio 2012 or how do I revert to the old functionality?

Comment: Do you want to reference a class in a different project.  If so, the functionality seems to be the same in VS 2012 and VS 2010.  What version of 2012 are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 Professional. The business objects are in the same project, not in an external assembly. This is a solution that was started in VS2010 and migrated to VS2012 for .NET 4.5 support. When I try to add an object data source through the conventional methods no classes or namespaces in the project are listed.

Comment: Worth noting that I have googled for a while and I've seen similar issues with folks using the Entity Framework which I am **not using** so I haven't found a workable solution. These business objects fall under the POCO (Plain Old CLR Objects) definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by right clicking on the solution and choosing clean and rebuilding everything. I'm now able to create a data source as described in my question.

Comment: Great.  I wasn't seeing the issue on my VS 2012.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with a single WinForm project. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution, yet I still do not see project objects in the list of objects. I even tried closing and restarting VS. No luck. Other solutions do display the local objects.